# vim colorscheme not rendering in windows command line

Tags: vim

It works perfectly in gvim, but in regular vim I can only switch to the built-in color schemes, not the external ones I installed (using pathogen). Why is this and can it be fixed?

Comment: What does "I can only switch to the built-in color schemes, not the external ones I installed" actually mean? Does it mean that you can't do `:color nameofyourcolorscheme` or that doing that has no discernable effect? What terminal emulator do you use? And what colorscheme are we talking about?

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot this issue, some general info from the help (`:help colorscheme`) suggests checking your runtimepath for the file
`colors/{name}.vim`:

```
:colo[rscheme] {name}   Load color scheme {name}.  This searches 'runtimepath'
            for the file "colors/{name}.vim".  The first one that
            is found is loaded.
            Also searches all plugins in 'packpath', first below
            "start" and then under "opt".
```

I guess pathogen should have installed them in `$HOME/.vim` (see `:help runtimepath`).

```
'runtimepath' 'rtp' string  (default:
                    Unix:  "$HOME/.vim,
                        $VIM/vimfiles,
                        $VIMRUNTIME,
                        $VIM/vimfiles/after,
```

So look for `$HOME/.vim/**/colors/{name}.vim` and see if the colorscheme you're
after can be found in the first place.

Comment: The installation process went fine, and the external color schemes do work in gvim. In normal vim though, it doesn't give an error but just stays in the default colorscheme

Comment: @AdarMaori Does vim apply all your other settings in the .vimrc? Also are you using vim/gvim on linux, mac, or windows? Also have you got `set t_Co=256` and `set termguicolors` in the vimrc?

Comment: 1: the rest of the .vimrc settings do work, and the application of the new colorscheme also works, but only in gvim.

2: I'm using windows 10 and vim 8.2

Comment: Then I'm not sure (especially if it's windows specific). The only other thing I
can think of is putting `set t_Co=256` and `set termguicolors` in your vimrc.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

set t_Co=256 and set termguicolors in your _vimrc file it worked for me hope it will work for you.